# sulu location countries list in admin limited

Tags: symfony, location, sulu

I am doing a project in Sulu 1.2 and I want to set an address in Canada but I can't seem to load the country.

Why is the country list in location type limited and how can I see all countries and where it can be modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior will be fixed with this PR: https://github.com/sulu/sulu/pull/2505

In the mean time you would have to override the [LocationContentType](https://github.com/wachterjohannes/sulu/blob/master/src/Sulu/Bundle/LocationBundle/Content/Types/LocationContentType.php) as described in the [Symfony Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#services-configuration).